# Как установить отдельно MS Access, когда сам Office установлен (2016г.)

Tags: access, office

Короче, проблема такая: на компьютере установлен MS Office 2016 года, туда входит Excel, Outlook, Word и еще какая-то прога. Мне нужно установить онли MS Access. Как мне это сделать не переустанавливая сам Office заново.
Заранее благодарствую
P.S. Пробовал использовать разные установщики, но это не помогало.

Comment: тогда других вариантов кроме как снести офис почти и не остается, можно конечно попробовать изменить программу через список программ но не уверен что получится, так как инсталировать новый компонент не получится вероятнее всего

Comment: *на компьютере установлен MS Office 2016 года* Какой именно? Если Проф - запускаешь установщик и добавляешь компоненты. Если тот, который "для дома" - придётся переустанавливать.

Comment: @Akina, походу установщик отсутствует, я такой вариант предложил ранее :D

Comment: @Akina, Для дома и бизнеса установлен. А без переустановки можно справиться?

Comment: *Для дома и бизнеса установлен. А без переустановки можно справиться?* Насколько я помню, этот вопрос поднимался на answers.microsoft.com, и кто-то из MVP ответил, что даже при наличии лицензии на Проф обновиться не получится, надо переустанавливать. Ссылку, само собой, уже не найду.

Comment: а в чем сложность с переустановкой офиса если не секрет?

Comment: ... тем более что у Офиса имеется целый мастер сохранения настроек.

Comment: вот и я о чем) резервировать можно даже в облако по-моему и откатится обратно

Comment: @Andrew Я сейчас в кампании на заказе, они все в данный момент работают через Excel. Если начну переустановку производство встанет на некоторое время (компьютеров всего 5)

Comment: @SkinnyD, просто учитывая все что вы нам сказали о условиях вероятность переустановки почти 100 проц)

Comment: @Andrew Установил среду выполнения Access, можно ли как-нибудь его активировать через ключ (он имеется), если я введу его в пункте "Сменить лицензию"? И да, сис. админ отсутствует поэтому там учетная запись не залогинина. Это не создаст каких-либо проблем?

Comment: то есть установить все-таки получилась?

Comment: @Andrew Да, среду выполнения. Делать в ней ничего не получится, кроме как запускать готовые БД.

Comment: @Andrew, поэтому интересно, смогу ли активировать его как-нибудь?

Comment: то есть у вас есть только среда без возможности создать бд, а вообще создавать нужно будет?

Comment: @Andrew Да, именно так. Создавать нужно будет.

Comment: я бы советовал все-таки начисто накатить офис, просто получается что у вас сейчас есть среда, в среде вы не сможете создать бд а только посмотреть, плюс не понятно как активировать, и тд и тп, в итоге будет куча костылей)) вы же не обязаны сразу на всех машинах ставить офис, можно по одной ставить) плюс как вариант можно обновиться, а то уже 21 год на дворе))

Comment: @Andrew Тоже так подумал, поэтому скорее всего так и поступлю. Спасибо огромное за помощь :)

Comment: кстати можете удаленно обновить все 5, по логике можно какой-то доступ расшарить на 5 машин и сэкономить время)

Comment: @Andrew у сис. админа есть доступ ко всем 5, поэтому остается только его ждать чтобы он переустановил все офисы и установил Access

Comment: рад что получилось частично решить вашу головную боль :)

Comment: @Andrew Да, спасибо Вам большое. Ибо уже 6 часов сижу над этим :)
Еще попробую активировать ключ, только если предоставят доступ к учетной записи, может что выйдет и он просто обновит весь Office. Спасибо еще раз за помощь и уделенное время :)